# I need help on finishing my nested for loop in C to produce a specific output

Tags: c, windows, for-loop, codeblocks, nested-loops

I am trying to write a nested for loop in order to produce the following output:

```
 01234
  2345
   456
    67
     8
```

The code I have so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 9

int main()
{
   int i, j;

   for(i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
      {
         if(i <= j)
         {
            printf("%d", j);
         }
         else
         {
            printf(" ");
         }
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
/* This produces:
 * 012345678
 *  12345678
 *   2345678
 *    345678
 *     45678
 *      5678
 *       678
 *        78
 *         8
/*
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Tip: `+= 2` instead of `++` in your loop

Comment: `printf("%d", j + i);` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int start,stop, k;
start = 0;
stop = SIZE/2 + SIZE%2;

while(start<=stop)
{
  for(k=0; k<start;++k)
      printf(" ");
  for(k=start;k<stop; ++k)
      printf("%d ", k);
printf("\n");

start+=2;
stop++;
}

printf("\n");
```

Analyze that common pattern is that `start` is increasing by 2 and `stop` is incremented by 1.
Loop will over when `start` overtakes `stop`.

Comment: Spoonfeed, thats not the best way to help

Comment: @AlterMann: Please edit the answer as required. Or should I edit or delete it?

Comment: There is nothing to edit, your answer is correct +1, but for learners a tip is better than a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the original question, but a solution to the task in the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEVEL 5

int
main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < LEVEL; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            printf(" ");
        for (j = i*2; j < LEVEL+i; j++)
            printf("%d", j);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i < SIZE/2 + 1; i++){
    for(j=0;j<i+SIZE/2 + 1;++j)
        if(j<i*2){
            printf(" ");
            ++j;
        } else
            printf("%d", j);
    printf("\n");
}
```